# Twig - getting text filed key and value

Tags: php, twig

I hav text filed where I stored some json data.

I am getting in my twig template on dump like:

```
"{"birthDate":"2021-09-01", "amount":8}"
```

I want to access keys so I can extract it's values.

Tried with [json_encode](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/json_encode.html) or:

```
{% for key, value in item.value %}
```

but nothing seems to work.

Is the problem with the output data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your item is neither object nor array it seems to be a string.

Try to convert your data to object or array json as below:

```
$objJson = json_decode($yourDBArray['menu']);
$arrJson = json_decode($yourDBArray['menu'],true);
```

Then you can use to show as below

```
{% for key,value in menu %}
    Key : {{ key }}
    Value : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: When you use `json_decode($yourDBArray['menu']);` to cast the `JSON` to an object you are not able to iterate over the properties/keys of said object by default in `twig`. So your first suggestion will not work with the `twig` snippet you've added